# Pasting image to fit in merged cell bug

Tags: vba, excel

I have two different subs which which places an image into a merged cell. The file selection method, distorts the image to fit both the height and width of the merged cell, no matter what size it is. The paste version however, will not do both the width & height. Only which ever one is used last within the programming code. How could I go about adjusting my sub paste, so that it distorts the image to fit both the width and height?

```
Sub FromFile()

    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim oShape As Shape

    If TypeName(ActiveSheet) <> "Worksheet" Then Exit Sub

    sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Images (*.gif;*.jpg;*.png), *.gif;*.jpg;*.png", _
        FilterIndex:=1, _
        Title:="Insert Picture", _
        ButtonText:="Insert", _
        MultiSelect:=False)
    If sFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

    With ActiveCell.MergeArea
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
                Filename:=sFileName, _
                LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                Left:=.Left, _
                Top:=.Top, _
                Width:=.Width, _
                Height:=.Height
    End With


End Sub


Public Sub Paste()
Dim p As Picture

    Dim s As Shape, rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("MyMerge")

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Intersect(rng, s.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
        Else
            s.Delete
        End If
    Next s

Worksheets("Report").Range("MyMerge").Select
With ActiveCell.MergeArea
    Set p = .Parent.Pictures.Paste
    p.Left = .Left
    p.Top = .Top
    p.Height = .Height
    p.Width = .Width
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps add `p.Shaperange.lockaspectratio = False` before sizing it?

Comment: @Rory This worked! Thank you for sharing Shaperange.lockaspectratio as I didn't know that was an option. Please place your comment in a form of an answer so I can reward you. Thank you.

Comment: .Parent.Pictures.Paste <~~ you must copy picture before paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
p.Shaperange.lockaspectratio = False
```

before resizing the picture and you should be able to alter both height and width independently.